# In Jest, how do I cause a function called within the function to return a specific value

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

This is the function I am testing (stripped down for simplicity's sake):
populate.js->

```
const { createSessionID } = require('./populate-template-utilities');

const createFile = async () => {
  const responseHeader = {};
  responseHeader.SessionID = createSessionID();
  return responseHeader;
};

module.exports = {
  createFile,
};
```

The function this function calls:
populate-template-utilities ->

```
const createSessionID = () => {
  const digits = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000000000) + 1000000000).toString();
  return `PAX${digits}`;
};

module.exports = {
  createSessionID,
};
```

And my unit test (again stripped down):

```
const { createSessionID } = require('../app/lib/populate-template-utilities');

describe('create XML for output files', () => {

  const mockID = jest
    .spyOn(createSessionID)
    .mockImplementation(() => 'PAX123456');

  it('should create a PAX File', async () => {
    const result = await createFile();
    expect(result).toEqual(getFile);
  });
});
```

I want createSessionID to return 'PAX123456' and think mockID should do it, but it's erroring with:

```
Cannot spy the undefined property because it is not a function; undefined given instead
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `spyOn` method needs at least [two parameters](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname): `object` and `methodName`.

Try sth like this:

```js
import * as populateTemplateUtils from "../sessionStuff";
import { createFile } from "../createFile";

describe('create XML for output files', () => {
  it('should create a PAX File', async () => {
    jest
      .spyOn(populateTemplateUtils, 'createSessionID')
      .mockReturnValue('PAX123456');

    const result = await createFile();
    expect(result).toEqual({"SessionID": "PAX123456"});
  });
});
```

It all started to work when I changed the:

```
module.exports = {
  createSessionID,
};
```

to:

```
export const createSessionID = () => {
```

Comment: Using the above, I am now not getting an error message, but the createSessionID isn't being mocked.

Comment: Updated my answer - it looks like you need to export your stuff differently.